# How can I get postgresql client-server protocol?

Tags: postgresql

I read the postgresql documentation, and I do know the protocol between client and server, the client and server can use text or binary format to represent data in different datatypes, but I don't know the specific way to transform data into text or binary that pg could recognize, is there any document that specify the binary or text protocol?

Comment: That's documented in the PostgreSQL source code.

Comment: Is there any other way to figure that out except reading the postgresql source code?

Comment: No, there is no way to figure out the PostgreSQL source code except reading it. But don't worry, it is well written and well documented.